# UWP UserControl + ContentControl

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to understand how content controls work and how I can place one inside a user control I'm constructing. From what I understand, my user control should have an object dependency property and then I should be able to add a content control to my user control and bind it to the dependency property.

I've tried variations of the User Control `XAML`, including bypassing the `ScrollViewer` element and placing the `ContentControl` inside the base grid of the User Control `XAML`.

How do I place this image inside this control? And more broadly how do I place any `XAML` inside a User Control?

**User Control CS**

```
namespace CoreProject.UserControls
{
public sealed partial class ZoomControl : UserControl
{
    public ZoomControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    #region Properties
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ZoomContentProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ZoomContent", typeof(object), typeof(ZoomControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    public object ZoomContent
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(ZoomContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ZoomContentProperty, value); }
    }
    #endregion

    public void UnZoom()
    {
        // unzoom
        ImageScrollViewer.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        var period = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10);
        Windows.System.Threading.ThreadPoolTimer.CreateTimer(async (source) =>
        {
            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                ImageScrollViewer.ChangeView(0.0, 0.0, 0.8F, true);
                ImageScrollViewer.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            });
        }, period);
    }

    public void ZoomToPosition(double zoomOriginX, double zoomOriginY, float zoomFactor, bool disableAnimations)
    {
        ImageScrollViewer.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        var period = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10);
        Windows.System.Threading.ThreadPoolTimer.CreateTimer(async (source) =>
        {
            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                ImageScrollViewer.ChangeView(zoomOriginX, zoomOriginY, 1.2F, disableAnimations);
            });
        }, period);
    }
}
```

}

**User Control Xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ImageScrollViewer" 
                  ZoomMode="Enabled" 
                  Visibility="Collapsed" 
                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
                  VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
                  Background="Transparent" 
                  HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
                  VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
        <Grid>
            <!-- HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO PLACE MY CONTENT -->
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding ZoomContent, ElementName=zoomContent}" />
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

**User Control Usage**

```
<usercontrols:ZoomControl x:Name="ZoomControl">
    <usercontrols:ZoomControl.ZoomContent>
        <!-- THIS IS HOW I WANT TO ADD MY CONTENT, SIMPLY PLACE XAML ELEMENT -->
        <Image Source="/Assets/colocationDataCenterData.jpg" />
    </usercontrols:ZoomControl.ZoomContent>
</usercontrols:ZoomControl>
```

Comment: `ElementName=zoomContent` -- You have no element named `zoomContent` in that scope, so there's no source for the binding. Try naming the UserControl `x:Name="userControl"` and bind to `ElementName=userControl`. That will mean "find a XAML element named `userControl` in this scope, and bind to that element's `ZoomComtent` property".

Comment: So `<usercontrols:ZoomControl x:Name="ZoomControl">` to `<usercontrols:ZoomControl x:Name="userControl">` is what you're referring to? And then update the `ElementName` to refer to that?

Comment: No. What if some parent control named some particular instance something else? That would break the control. What if you had two instances in the same parent? They'd have to have different names, so only one could work. It's also out of scope for the XAML inside the user control anyway.

Comment: No, the UserControl XAML has a root tag of `UserControl` inside `MyUserControl.xaml`. Give *that* the name. In the scope where the name will be used.

Comment: Sorry I'm still confused :/

Comment: Is there a file in your project named `ZoomControl.xaml`?

Comment: Yes there is. And it has a root tag of UserControl. I have not given it an x:Name yet.

Comment: Give it a name and use the name for `ElementName` in your binding

Comment: Thanks, just go it working. I understand this all a lot better now.

Comment: You can do it via code as well like `YourContentControlContent.Content = new UserControl()`

Answer (score 3):

```
 <Grid>
     <!-- HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO PLACE MY CONTENT -->
     <ContentControl Content="{x:Bind ZoomContent, Mode=OneWay}" />
 </Grid>
```

You can also use x:Bind instead - it takes the Binding context as the class itself (your UserControl), so you can straight bind.

If you want classical binding to work you need to name and userControl INSIDE the usercontrol itself. (BTW, typically you'd do this as a TEMPLATED control instead and use templatebindings)

```
<UserControl x:Name="zoomContent">
    <Grid>
         <ScrollViewer x:Name="ImageScrollViewer" 
              ZoomMode="Enabled" 
              Visibility="Collapsed" 
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
              VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
              Background="Transparent" 
              HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
              VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
         <Grid>
             <!-- HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO PLACE MY CONTENT -->
             <ContentControl Content="{Binding ZoomContent, ElementName=zoomContent}" />
         </Grid>
     </ScrollViewer>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```